# Display menu compilation error

Tags: java, menu, compiler-errors

I'm just confused over why there is a compilation error and how should I fix it. Also, in the last if statement when user fails to enter a valid integer, I'm supposed to repeat the menu again. How should I do that? Thanks in advance.

```
 public class MainMenu {
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     System.out.println("My First Java program can do many things!");
     System.out.println("1.Estimate population\n2.Generate random integer\n3. Print ASCII      table\n4. Approximate pi by iteration");
     System.out.println("What would you like to do? (1-4)");
     System.out.print("Your choice: ");
     int input = 0;
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     switch (keyboard.nextInt())
     {
         case 1:
             System.out.println("You chose to estimate population.");
             break;
         case 2:
             System.out.println("You chose to generate random integer.");
             break;
         case 3:
             System.out.println("You chose to print ASCII table.");
             break;
         case 4:
             System.out.println("You chose to approximate pi by iteration.");
             break;
     }

     if(input>4 || input<1)
     {
         System.out.println("Sorry, I don't know what to do. Please try again.");   
         keyboard.next();
         if(!keyboard.hasNextInt()) 
    {
         System.out.println("Sorry, only integers allowed for this menu. Good-bye!");
         System.exit(0);
     }
  keyboard.next();
  input = keyboard.nextInt();
  keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Right off the bat, I'm going to point out that you have three statements (starting with keyboard.next();) outside of the MainMenu class.

Comment: stdin copy
Standard input is empty
compilation info
Main.java:35: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error
  stdout
Standard output is empty

Comment: So move those three statements into your class. The very last thing in any class definition should be a right curly brace.

Comment: I did that. Now it prints up till "your choice" and the rest shows "Main.java:48: error: reached end of file while parsing
}"

Comment: You should consider formatting and indenting your code properly. That way checking for missing curly braces and parentheses and such will be a lot easier.

Comment: Where are you getting line 48? You didn't post more than 40 lines of code there. Did you post ALL of your code? Anyhow, please stop and use your head for a second. You have the same error as the first time, but on a different line. What should you be doing now (other than asking to be spoon fed).

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks much for the input.

Answer (score 0):

your code need lot of changes to make it work, first you need continuous loop which will run continuously and wait for the user input. Then you have to catch a InputMismathexeption if the input is other than integer, that you have to do in the beginning of the code.
 it is bad idea to supply the code, which will stop from you trying different ways. Still I am attaching the code.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("My First Java program can do many things!");
System.out.println("1.Estimate population\n2.Generate random integer\n3. Print   ASCII      table\n4. Approximate pi by iteration");
    System.out.println("What would you like to do? (1-4)");
    System.out.print("Your choice: ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        int input = 0;
        try {
            input = keyboard.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Sorry, only integers allowed for this menu. Good-bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        switch (input) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You chose to estimate population.");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You chose to generate random integer.");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You chose to print ASCII table.");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You chose to approximate pi by iteration.");
            break;
        }

        if (input > 4 || input < 1) {
            System.out
                    .println("Sorry, I don't know what to do. Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
}
```